# Allow entering a URL as the target room when moving messages in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

When moving messages from one chatroom to another, there is a popup to enter the target room name. After entering a substring of the room name, a list of matching rooms appear, and we select the target by clicking the “choose” button next to the desired room.

Please allow entering a room URL (`http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/$number` or `http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/$number/slug` or `http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/$number` or other variants) instead of the name.